# Simple MVC.net page in Visual Studio debugging

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to this website and to Visual Studio, but I am trying to create a page that would take a string from the server as soon as the page loads, and will also have a button that if pressed will request another string from the server. I have one controller and one view. I am following this website's advice:
http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html

So in my "About" View I have:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<button type="button" id="btn">click the button</button>
<p id="rData">hello</p>

<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript">
    var url = "/HomeController/getData";
    $.get(url,null, function (data) {
        $("#rData").html(data);
    });

 $('#btn').click(function () {
 var url = "/HomeController/getMoreData";
 $.get(url, null, function (data) {
  $("#rData").html(data);
});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
        public ActionResult About()
         {
          return View();
      }
    public String getData() {

        return DateTime.Today.ToString(); 
    }
    public String getMoreData()
    {
        return "hi";
    }
```

Nevertheless, when I look at the page in the browser, the functions inside the script tags are not performed (I just see original HTML layout).

Do you happen to know why this happens?

Thank you in advance!

Yan

Comment: Using Chrome and the Developer Tools do you see any errors? For one, I can't see a reference to jQuery in your markup.

Comment: Hi maxbeaudoin! Thank you for your response. I included jquery into my script tag, but when I look at the webpage in Chrome I still just see original HTML tags, and I see no errors in the Developer Tools

Comment: Errors in the Developer Tools are useful for debugging web apps. Start from there and consider including the errors that you can't work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and corrected the errors.Now its working

**Orginal code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<button type="button" id="btn">click the button</button>
<p id="rData">hello</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "/HomeController/getData";
    $.get(url,null, function (data) {
        $("#rData").html(data);
    });

 $('#btn').click(function () {
 var url = "/HomeController/getMoreData";
 $.get(url, null, function (data) {
  $("#rData").html(data);
});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Corrected Code:**

```
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="btn">click the button</button>
<p id="rData">hello</p>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "/Home/getData";
            $.get(url, null, function (data) {
                $("#rData").html(data);
            });

            $('#btn').click(function () {
                var url = "/Home/getMoreData";
                $.get(url, null, function (data) {
                    $("#rData").html(data);
                });
            })
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Important Highlights:**

Very important thing I corrected was, you have put    var url = "/HomeController/getData";    this not necessary and it wont work. You have to give the controller name, alone that is var url = "/Home/getData";

And another thing noted was , the start of the body tag and script reference was missing  in the above code.

Now Everything was corrected , it is working

**Additional info:**

I added that  working cshtml alone in github for your convenience , you may  take and use it If you want .Here is the link: https://github.com/KarthikElumalai/jqueryproj

Hope the information will be useful, kindly let me know your thought or feedbacks

Thanks
Karthik

Comment: My pleasure and happy that it helped..Love sharing...:)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jQuery script reference in your client side code. Once you add that you can use the $.get method. Add the following before your script tags.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js">
    </script>
```

You also don't need to specify HomeController, just Home. Here is a sample:

```
<button id="test" onclick="btnClicked();">Try it</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function btnClicked(){
        $.get( "Home/ClickThis", function( data ) {
            alert( data );
        });
    }

</script>
```

In  the Home controller, add a method:

```
        public string ClickThis()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("D");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think the main issue was that I forgot to end the ending script tag after jQuery script reference

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>
<h1 id="h1">Zdorovo</h1>
<h2 id="h2"> Privet </h2>
<button id="btn">Try it</button>
<p id="id"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    var url = "/Home/getData";
    $.get(url, null, function (data) {
        $("#id").html(data);
    });


    </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                var url = "/Home/getMoreData";
                $.get(url, null, function (data) {
                    $("#id").html(data);
                });
            })

</script>
```